# Facebook App - {"error":{"message":"(#1) An error occured while creating the share","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When my app tries to post on "friends wall" sometimes i receive this error:

```
{"error":
    {"message":"(#1) An error occured while creating the share",
     "type":"OAuthException",
     "code":1}
}
```

I'm sure to have (and to use) long `access_token` and `publish_stream` permission, in fact sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Do you have any idea about the cause of the problem?

Comment: Please provide details of an actual post causing that issue. Is the access token timing out? You will need to exchange it for a longer-living one, described here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Ciao. As I wrote i have long access token valid for 60 days. This is sure!

Comment: I am afraid that now Facebook returns a generic error message that include old errore message as "max post limit per day" or "limit to post for your friend option", ecc...
That would be very sad for developers!

Answer (score 1):

The ability to post on a friend's wall has been deprecated and will be removed in 90 days (for the reasons described in this blog post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

Whilst that doesn't directly answer your question, it does make it moot and you should take an alternative approach (also described in the post)